# Connected device IP address not found in ARP command

Tags: tcp, arp, netsh

I am hosting a virtual network allowing devices connect via the access point and then start tcp/ip communication with the devices. However, the device is connected as shown in the picture, but not found in "arp -a" command (an ip-mac address matching table).

Is my device connected correctly or I have missed out something?

[Detected device (mac address 00:08:dc:00:00:00) is connected to my virtual network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvOsi.jpg)

[The connected device (00:08:dc:00:00:00) is not found in the arp matching table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmuzU.jpg)

Comment: what is the condition to record the devices' address in arp table??

Comment: The device never shows in arp table, does it mean it never connects to my network?

Answer (score 0):

ARP table only records communicated devices. If it does not show up in the table but it should be, ping all the address in your network (as you don't know its actual address), it will show properly.